# Restrict Bootstrap Input tags maximum 100 tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tags-input

Hi friends I'm using bootstrap Tags input for my project , but I require only 100 tags to be entered after that it should not allow the tags to be entered into the input field .

HTML :

```
<input type="text"  class="form-control" id="skill_nameone" name="skill_name"  data-role="tagsinput"  />
```

JS:

```
bootstrap-tagsinput.min
```

CSS :

```
bootstrap-tagsinput.css
```

Image :

[image]

This input field should accommodate only 100 tags . In above pic it contains 7 Tags .

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can limit the maximum number of tags by using `maxTags` like this:

```
$('input').tagsinput({
  maxTags: 100
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check in the **.js file**. Find the word **maxTags:undefined**. Change the world **undefined** to the number you want to limit.

Comment: This would change the max tags for every single input you make, you shouldn't modify the bootstrap library to make changes for a single input.